# SBT: Append setting in sequence inside PlayKeys.devSettings

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am working in Play framework for Java and I have need to add certain custom made modules during the development.
So far, I was doing this by adding new conf file that has following content:

```
include "application.conf"
play.modules.enabled += "DevModule"
```

and running sbt like this:

```
sbt -Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf
```

On [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile) I found that it is possible to use PlayKeys.devSettings and override Play setting of your choice. It would be good if I can use that syntax and something like this in build.sbt:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.modules.enabled" -> "DevModule")
```

However this one does not work as I am getting this exception during the runtime:

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[hardcoded value: 
play.modules.enabled has type STRING rather than LIST]
```

I understand that `"DevModule"` needs to be inserted in the list of `"play.modules.enabled"`, but I have no idea how to do this in sbt since I do not know Scala.

Answer (score 0):

PlayKeys.devSettings expect `Seq[(String, String)])` to be provided. 
Try this form, similar like you would write in conf file:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings :=  Seq(""""play.modules.enabled+="""" -> "DevModule")
```

This is how settings are applied to a list.
You can debug contents of your config by printlning somewhere in your controller e.g.:

```
//...other imports
import com.typesafe.config.Config

class ApplicationController @Inject()(
  config: Config
  //...
) extends MessagesAbstractController(cc) {

  def index() = Action{ implicit r =>
    println(config.getList("play.modules.enabled"))
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```

Comment: build.sbt is now compiled, but DevModule is not included in the build. I think that, somehow in sbt, I need to get the List named `play.modules.enabled` and append String `DevModule`. `"play.modules.enabled +="` does not seem to do anything.
E.g. something like this works `PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "8080")`, but `http.server.http.port` expects String.

Comment: That's strange, I tried it on my own project and printing contents of config `play.modules.enabled`. Sorry for silly question, do you have  another `PlayKeys.devSettings :=` somewhere below in `build.sbt` that could possibly override this setting?

Comment: I tried to display all the configuration values with given method, but `play.modules.enabled` does not have mine `DevModule` in it. With your suggested solution I can see the following key inside Configuration `play.modules.enabled+=`, but that is not what I need.
if I manually add config file during the starting of the sbt, `DevModule` is visible in Configuration